# How do you assign a datepicker from a textbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have the user input a date in one datepicker, then underneath input the number of weeks between the two dates. The second datepicker will then assign that date weeks, days or years later.

This is the code I have:

I have the two datepickers and the textbox:

```
<datepicker x:name="Date1"
="" focusable="False" displaydate="01/01/2022" displaydatestart="01/01/2022" displaydateend="12/31/2022" istodayhighlighted="True">

<textbox x:name="Text 1"
="" tooltip="Enter the number of weeks between dates" background="AliceBlue" borderbrush="Black" borderthickness="2" textalignment="Center" horizontalalignment="Stretch">

<datepicker x:name="Date2"
="" focusable="False" displaydate="01/01/2022" displaydatestart="01/01/2022" displaydateend="12/31/2022">
```

Comment: Date2.SelectedDate = Date1.SelectedDate.AddDays(AmountOfDays*7);

Answer (score 0):

Try something this:

```
if (int.TryParse(Text1.Text, out int weeksToAdd) && Date1.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    Date2.SelectedDate = Date1.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(7 * weeksToAdd);
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment but it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Other ideas. I presented a complete solution to your issue more or less. What doesn't work exactly? What's the value of the `TextBox` and the `DatePicker` when you execute the code?

Comment: So the program stops running and says that nullable type are null. It also says that datepicker does not contain an AddDate feature. The value of the TextBox is Text 1 and it is set to read only while the two values for the date picker is Date 1 and Date 2

Comment: There is no "AddDate" present in the code I posted so your error is obviously elsewhere.